# Concurrent Sound on Android Device

Tags: android, concurrency, audio, multi-touch, soundpool

I have been developing simple drum pads for my phone and have run into a block when it comes to playing two sounds at once (ie during a multitouch event when the user presses down on two or more drum sounds at the same time).

For playing the sounds I have been using the SoundPool class. I have a HashMap that hashes a Point to a sound. So my thinking was that when a point is pressed, its corresponding sound will be played.

I have a feeling that getting two sounds to play at once involves forking or creating new threads, but it did not work the way I tried it, which is just creating a new thread in a "for each" loop for each point pressed.

Thanks in advance!
-Aneem

EDIT:

```
SoundPool database = new SoundPool(6,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100);



protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); //switched for convenience
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    screenFactor = (int)((height*width)/6);

    //have to add all points to the hash map
    widthIncrement = (int)(width/3);
    heightIncrement = (int)(height/2);

    pointMap.put(new Point(0,0), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.clv,1));
    pointMap.put(new Point(widthIncrement,0), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.pedalhh,1));
    pointMap.put(new Point((widthIncrement*2),0), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.shake,1));
    pointMap.put(new Point(0,heightIncrement), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.analoghat,1));
    pointMap.put(new Point(widthIncrement,heightIncrement), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.kick,1));
    pointMap.put(new Point((widthIncrement*2),heightIncrement), database.load(getContext(),R.raw.snare,1));

}
```

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

```
    if(ev.getAction()==ev.ACTION_DOWN){
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int streamVolume = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        PointF[] touchPoints = new PointF[ev.getPointerCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < ev.getPointerCount(); i++){
            if(ev.getPointerId(i)==ev.ACTION_DOWN){
                touchPoints[i] = new PointF(ev.getX(i),ev.getY(i));
            }
        }
        int i = 1;
        for(final PointF point : touchPoints){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){                      
                    forkSound(point);       
                }
            }).start();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SoundPool is capable of playing multiple things at once. You pass in the number of streams when you set up the SoundPool.

Post all of your code that deals with creating and setting up your soundpool and we can see why it is not working how you want.

[SoundPool Constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

The first parameter is int maxStreams. Whatever you pass for this parameter will be how many streams your soundpool can play at once

Comment: No problem. It looks like you are creating it with 6 streams so it should be able to play 6 sounds at once. Can you post the code where you are calling play? Also what does it do when you try to play more than one at once? Does it play them in sequence or only play 1 of them?

Comment: I've been messing around with the app a little more, and I think the problem actually isn't with SoundPool, it's how I've been handling multitouch. So basically when I try to play more than one, only one of them plays. I'll post up my code for handling touch events.